# How does one “document” the flow of a complex code base? After the fact…

Tags: architecture, documentation, code-readability

I’m a one-man band that has developed a SaaS offering for an existing clientele of ~60k.

I am a self-taught guy, starting with my Tandy 2500XL.

And have worked on enterprise projects with a team since then.

But…

Not only is the complexity of this project becoming heady for me; what about someone trying to follow my code base?

THE Question: What is the best mechanism, process flow software or otherwise, for me to illustrate this monster?

How should I think about this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, while it's not a bad question in its own right, it probably belongs on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fwiw, though; this is a complex topic but a good start is an automatic documentation generation tool (not sure what is available for js - OP tagged next.js pre-edit; but things like doxygen, javadoc, etc), which can generate browseable docs from inline source documentation, as well as various call and dependency graphs; similar tools and strategies for other pieces too, e.g. db schemas, etc. That, plus high level docs that you write yourself, usually gets most (not all) of the job done.

Comment: I was concerned I placed it in the wrong place. Thank you for your thoughts @JasonC. I'll kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Moving question to an appropriate platform.